# Hibernate Reverse Engineering using DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering, hibernate-tools, hbm

I am trying to generate the pojos and hbm files using DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy. I am able to customize things like implementing interface, toString method, eager fetch for all table objects.

However, I need to customize two more features:

Consider two table Parent and Child where there is one to many relationship between Parent and Child.

I would like to:

1. set inverse="false" for Child collection in Parent hbm
2. set cascade="all" for Child collection in parent hbm so that if I update Parent collection it should cascade the effect to child collection.

   ```
   <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.xyz.Parent" table="PARENT" schema="FAMILY">
     <meta attribute="implements" inherit="false">SomeInterface</meta>
     <meta attribute="extra-import" inherit="false">com.xyz.SomeInterface</meta>
      <property name="parentColumn" type="date">
       <meta attribute="use-in-tostring" inherit="false">true</meta>
       <column name="PARENT_COLUMN" length="7" />
     </property>
    <set name="child" table="Child" **inverse="false"** lazy="false" fetch="select" **cascade="all"**>
    <key>
      ....
     </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.xyz.Child" />
    </set>
   </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
   ```
3. exclude Parent as foreign key in Child's hbm - to avoid reverse look up in the code.

   ```
   <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.xyz.Child" table="CHILD" schema="FAMILY">
     <meta attribute="implements" inherit="false">SomeInterface</meta>
     <meta attribute="extra-import" inherit="false">com.xyz.SomeInterface</meta> 
     <property name="childColumn" type="date">
       <meta attribute="use-in-tostring" inherit="false">true</meta>  
       <column name="CHILD_COLUMN" length="7" />
     </property>
   </composite-id>
   **-- I do not want this in CHILD 
   <many-to-one name="parent" class="com.xyz.Parent" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
   <meta attribute="use-in-tostring" inherit="false">true</meta>
   ....
   </many-to-one>**
   </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
   ```

Is there a way to find out the association info in DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy? Some Class that can give one-to-many, one-to-one etc. information for each Table.

Answer (score 1):

Appears that it should be possible by overriding DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy.foreignKeyToAssociationInfo(ForeignKey) however the function doesn't seem to be called at all during the the entity creation build :(

Can just do a regex replace after the build is complete via maven. Somethign like
Find

```
@ManyToOne\((.*)\)[\r\n\s]+@JoinColumn\((.*)\)[\r\n\s]+public Entity getEntity\(\)
```

Replace with

```
@ManyToOne($1, cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)\r\n\t@JoinColumn($2, updatable=false, insertable=false)\r\n\tpublic Entity getEntity()
```